# Adding Users to Parse Role in Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, roles

I want to add users to my Parse.Role but it's not working.  I looked at a number of examples and they all seem pretty straight-forward however I'm unable to get it right. Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("activateVendor", function(request, response){
     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
     query.equalTo("name", "vendor");
     query.first ({
          success: function(role) {
               role.getUsers().add(request.params);//request.params is the parse object, should I be using request.params.id?
               role.save();
          },
          error: function(error) {
               throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
          }
      })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who you wish added to the role.  The user who made the cloud request is available via the request object...

```
role.getUsers().add(request.user);
```

Otherwise, you can get a user via a query as @RobertRowntree suggests.  (though, I'd suggest doing it with promises).

Answer (score 1):

does what you want with 2 queries (Role, User) ...

```
  var qu = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var qr = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  qr.get(roleId, {
  success: function(role) {
      _role = role;
      qu.get(userId, {
        success: function(user) {
            _role.getACL().setRoleReadAccess(_role, true);
            _role.getUsers().add(user);
            _role.save();
            response.success(_role.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(object, error) {

        }
      });
  },
  error: function(object, error) {

  }
});
```